# How to store firebase user email and password in Ionic Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, ionic-storage

I'm new to ionic 3 and firebase. I have built an application that uses email and password to authenticate users. Right now whenever you quit the app, It logs the user out and they have to re-login which can be a hassle.
I have seen hints of some users saving the user credentials (email and password) in Storage (@ionic/storage) so the next time they use the app it will automatically sign them in.
Is this the correct way to go about this? And if so, could I please see and example? Any help would be great.

Comment: Never save the user's credentials on the device. Are you using `onAuthStateChanged` to detect that the user is signed in?

Comment: I have used `onAuthStateChanged` to get the currently signed in user it looked something like:    `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    });`

Comment: However this never solution never worked for me. I have built to ios multiple times to test this and whenever I login and then close the app the `navCtrl` never pushes past the authentication and the users have to sign in again. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: There are cases where `localStorage` is not persisted in ionic, low memory in iOS devices. Firebase Auth is working on migrating to `indexedDB` as it is more reliable. You need to investigate the root cause of this. Try saving data in `localStorage` and then restart the app. If data is lost then this is the problem. You could try to back the data in `indexedDB` or some other more persistent/reliable storage and then on app launch copy it back to `localStorage`. You can use that until Firebase Auth fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, but it better store with checked checkbox 'Remember me', that allows user to make choise use it or not.

And i prefer use NativeStorage

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';

let login: string;

constructor(private nativeStorage: NativeStorage, ...) {
    this.login = '';
}
```

Store example:

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('LOGIN', 'Your Value').then(
    () => {
        // Do something, optional
    },
    error => {

    }
);
```

Getting example:

```
this.nativeStorage.getItem('LOGIN').then(
    (data) => {
        // Get value and put it into our variable
        this.login = data;
    },
    error => {

    }
);
```

And use it in your view:

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="login" type="text"></ion-input>
```

More info about NativeStorage:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/

Comment: Storing plain text password credentials on the user's device is one of the worst security practices.

Comment: Why negative? :) It is just example how to store and get, not full solution, obviously. Of course, password must be encrypted, or, store only username. And decision, how to do it, depends on back-end.

Comment: This is Web Security 101. Passwords must be hashed and salted with strong one way hashing algorithms and stored server side (never in plain text). Firebase issues tokens that can be revoked along with ID tokens that are short lived. I can understand if you provided a way to store these tokens, but storing a user's password on the device is strongly discouraged. Your answer is an endorsement of this bad practice and shouldn't be encouraged especially with constant news of user credentials getting leaked due to bad security practices.

Comment: Okay, you right. And i have not recommed store passwords. I only show how to use NativeStorage without password, only username, for example.